# How do I prevent nginx from stripping secure cookies?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, http-cookie

We're setting the [`secure` flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie) on our cookies and nginx is refusing to transmit them because we're communicating with it over HTTP.

This is perfectly understandable, as that is the expected behavior. However, in front of nginx, we run a Classic Load Balancer (previously known as the Elastic Load Balancer) which accepts HTTPS traffic from the internet and talks to nginx on our internal network via HTTP.

So, is there a way to tell nginx not to strip the cookies, as the connection overall is trusted?

Comment: On closer inspection. This might not be related to nginx at all, but an express issue. I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, first of all, when you're debugging a "weird" issue with HTTP cookie based sessions, make sure to check if the appropriate `Set-Cookie` header is even sent by the server!

When you established that it is *not* being sent (as I did), you're going to want to set the environment variable `DEBUG` to `*`, in case you're running a NodeJS/express application.

If you do so, you might spot the following line in your logs:

> cookie-session error saving session Cannot send secure cookie over unencrypted connection

You'll then track that line down to [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/4a420e4449fcc4c16c345dc9b5c561fc7daa8018/index.js#L113) and then further down to [cookies](https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies/blob/e2aedb1bff6f26147895d7ee9a19d4345c6236d9/lib/cookies.js#L79). Which is when you realize that this all has to do with express not treating the connection as trusted.

So nginx isn't *stripping* any cookies. In a way, it is to blame though. I found the answer in [nginx $scheme variable behind load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230918/nginx-scheme-variable-behind-load-balancer). To quote the accepted answer:

```
# Sets a $real_scheme variable whose value is the scheme passed by the load
# balancer in X-Forwarded-Proto (if any), defaulting to $scheme.
# Similar to how the HttpRealIp module treats X-Forwarded-For.
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $real_scheme {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
```

You would put that into your nginx configuration and then use `$real_scheme` instead of `$scheme` for the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header:

```
proxy_set_header "X-Forwarded-Proto" $real_scheme;
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, nginx doesn't do any processing related to `secure` flag.

Comment: Good to know. But, yeah, I was completely on the wrong track :)